# VueJS nexttick and IE11

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer-11

Recently $nexttick appears to have broken on IE 11, in particular regarding input bound variable. This is causing forms with dynamic content to submit missing the required data

```
<form id="something" action="/" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" :value="token" />
</form>

// js code
promise.then(function() {
    self.$nextTick(function () {
        document.getElementById('something').submit();
    });
});
```

We have found that using the setTimeout for 1 second around the form submission allows enough time for the DOM to be updated so the token can be included in the form submission.

Has there been any changes to nexttick / IE11 that we need to account for?

Answer (score 0):

[nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) allows you to do something after you have changed the data and VueJS has updated the DOM based on your data change, but **before the browser has rendered those changed on the page**. If you want to explicitly re-render the DOM, use **requestAnimationFrame** or **setTimeout**.

You could check [this thread](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/9200).